# How to execute a command only for particular arch?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to make a generic `gdbinit` for both native and remote GDB, where native is i386, and remote is ARM. For i386 I have `set disassembly-flavor intel` command, which breaks initialization for ARM-targeted GDB.

The only thing I found which lets me know arch (at least i386 vs ARM) is
`show arch` command, but it just prints its output to stdout, not allowing me to get it for comparison.

So, is there any way to execute a command only for some architectures but not not ohers?

Comment: Can you use the Python plugin?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer not sure what type of plugin you mean. If you mean typing `python` and some python code inside `gdbinit`, then I guess I can. I just don't know what part of GDB Python API to use there to get arch before there's any inferior running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just ignore the error using the Python plug-in:

```
python
try:
   gdb.execute("set disassembly-flavor intel")
except:
   pass
end
```

Or you could check the architecture:

```
python
if "(currently i386)" in gdb.execute("show arch", to_string=True):
  gdb.execute("set disassembly-flavor intel")
end
```